# MySQL query to get all highest id's

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table or queryresult like this.

```
    id  name url
    --- ---- ---
    1   AAA  http://aaa.com?r=123
    2   AAA  http://aaa.com?r=456
    1   BBB  http://bbb.com?r=xyz
    2   BBB  http://bbb.com?r=qsd
    3   BBB  http://bbb.com?r=fgh
    4   BBB  http://bbb.com?r=jkl
    1   CCC  http://ccc.com?r=a23
    3   CCC  http://ccc.com?r=bc6
```

What I actually want is to get all unique names with the highest id.  So basically this.

```
    id  name url
    --- ---- ---
    2   AAA  http://aaa.com?r=456
    4   BBB  http://bbb.com?r=jkl
    3   CCC  http://ccc.com?r=bc6
```

What can I add or change to a query to get that result.

The proposed solutions do not work or return wrong results

**OK finally I seem to have found it myself, this seems to work:**

```
SELECT id, name, url
FROM yourtable
WHERE concat(id, name) IN 
(SELECT concat(max(id), name) FROM yourtable GROUP BY name)



id  name url
   --- ---- ---
   2   AAA  http://aaa.com?r=456
   4   BBB  http://bbb.com?r=jkl
   3   CCC  http://ccc.com?r=bc6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works without using Concat

```
SELECT yt.id, 
    yt.name, 
    yt.url
FROM yourtable yt
INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT max(id) id ,
         name 
         FROM yourtable GROUP BY name) maxyt
ON yt.id  = maxyt.id
   AND yt.name = maxyt.name;
```

Using `concat(id, name)` may work but it suffers from two problems.

1. Its definitely not SARGable (I'm not 100% sure my solution is)
2. It will cause problems if someone puts in a name like 1AAA, Since the `Concat(11,'AAA')` = `Concat (1,'1AAA')`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, name, url
FROM yourtable
WHERE id IN (SELECT max(id) FROM yourtable GROUP BY name))
```

The inner query fetches the highest ID number for every 'name' in the table, then the outer query uses those IDs to fetch the rest of the rows those IDs occur on.

Comment: This is the only one that does the job.

Comment: still doesn't do what I want, although I believe it's in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Add `GROUP BY id ORDER BY id ASC`

Something like

```
SELECT id, name, url FROM yourtable GROUP BY id ORDER BY id ASC
```

Comment: Would that work? On SQL Server it wouldn't. `GROUP BY` has to come before `ORDER BY`.

Comment: wouldn't you want `ORDER BY id DESC` ?

Comment: No, he wants from highest to lowest in terms of 1, 2 , 3, 4

Comment: I meant as in the language SQL-92. Your solution doesn't work. "Column 'yourtable.name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." You can only select the items you group on AND aggregate functions, like `MAX` or `SUM`.

Comment: That returns an error in mysql: [ERROR in query 2] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group by id' at line 11

Comment: @ Bruce it doesn't really matter in what order the results are returned all I want is that for each name it returns the row with the highest id.

Comment: TRY -> SELECT id, name, url, sum(id) as sum FROM yourtable GROUP BY id

Answer (score 0):

Got it finally.

```
SELECT id, name, url, sum(id) as demosum FROM table_name GROUP BY name ORDER BY ID DESC
```

This should work.

Comment: No it returns completely different results

Comment: SELECT max(id), name, url FROM table_name GROUP BY name ORDER BY ID ASC